# ¿Como puedo cancelar un evento ngOnDestoy() en angular 2+?

Tags: angular

Como puedo mostrar un mensaje de confirmación al cambiar de componente en `Angular 2`.

Ejemplo: Si tengo un formulario y lleno información y de pronto presiono un botón "Atrás" (que me envía a otro componente) que se muestre un mensaje o alert  que diga "*La información ingresada se perderá esta seguro? SI o NO"*, si presiono No se cancele el evento ngOnDestroy().

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes Daniel, te recomiendo leas [**_¿Como Preguntar?_**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para darle una formulación mas correcta a tu pregunta, ademas has el [**_Recorrido_**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor el sitio y ganar tu primer medalla!

Comment: La pregunta es demasiado amplia: ¿quieres un componente modal para hacer eso o simplemente quieres usar algo como [`window.confirm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm)?

Comment: Cualquier mensaje que me permita detener el evento ngOnDestroy()

Comment: creo que podrías resolver tu problema de otra forma, en vez de cerrar el formulario al apretar "Atrás" podrías abrir una pregunta (modal, alert, cuadro de dialogo, etc) que pregunte si quieres salir si presionas si pues ahí destruyes el formulario y si no pues no lo haces

Comment: Eso esta muy bien, pero como haría si el usuario presionara el botón atrás del navegador?

Answer (score 0):

El ciclo de vida de los componentes de angular no se debe tocar, lo que tienes que hacer es directamente evitar que se destruya tu componente. ¿Cómo? Pues sencillamente no lo quites de tu página. Si tienes un botón que te envía a otro componente, haz algo como lo siguiente:

En la plantilla:

```
<button (click)="goBack()">Atrás</button>
```

En tu componente:

```
goBack() {
  if (window.confirm("La información ingresada se perderá ¿Estás seguro?")) {
    //código para mostrar a otro componente, podría ser algo como
    this.router.navigate(['/index']);
  }
}
```